# redirecting main blog url

Tags: wordpress, redirect, blogs

If I have a wordpress blog, is it possible to have the main url to redirect to a basic HTML page, while keeping the permalinks still displaying the blog posts within a wordpress theme?

Comment: @ben - He means that you should ask this question at http://superuser.com/ as it's not really programming-related

Answer (score 2):

Set your front-page to a custom (static) page (Settings -> Reading in WP 2.8)

[More info here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Using_a_Page_as_the_Front_Page)